# What type of Google Analytics Property for Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

When setting up [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) what type of Google Analytics Property should I create?

There does not seem to be a "Universal Analytics" or "Measurement Protocol" option, which is the source of my confusion and the reason for my question.

The two choices are Web Site and Mobile Application, and both seem to need configuration beyond what is suggested as the requirements in the Measurement Protocol page.

Comment: The measurement protocol doesn't care if its universal or application Google analytics its up to you to send the correct data for the different types of analytics accounts.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out, but I did create both Mobile and Web properties. Only the Web Property type will accept events and page views from Measurement Protocol API. I was sending events from a mobile application (in C++) to both Mobile and Web Properties, and only Web Properties were recording the events.

Comment: Send screenviews to mobil pageviews to web

Comment: Definitely send pageviews to web and screenviews to mobile. Also, define all additional required properties as specified in the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters and ensure that all hits are validated against the correct Property using hit-builder.

Comment: There are a few undocumented required fields for Application accounts.   Check out the app fields if I remember there are 4 of them app name app version ans a couple of others

Comment: If they are undocumented, then I was not passing them. I was passing only the the fields that were specified in the documentation as required (for web and mobile property types, as they are different at least in Google's published documentation.)

Comment: They are in the documentation it just doesn't state that they are required.   I was bit buy this last year.   This might help http://www.daimto.com/monitoring-quota-usage-for-google-apis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Measurement Protocol is property-agnostic. If you go to this hit-builder site, https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/, you will notice that it doesn't ask what type of property you are using (ie. UA vs classic GA). It just needs to know the property ID, type of hit, client ID, and version number.

Comment: I agree that it should be property-agnostic, but my testing results do not agree with this theory. I created both property types and submitted hits validated with hit builder to both property types. Only the "Web Property" logged the information. The Mobile Property did not.

Comment: Can you show the hits you were sending to both the web and mobile app properties?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but it does not match my results -- the Measurement Protocol is property-agnostic but the API isn't. Hit Builder does ask what type of property you are using (it queries it from the property you selected.) I was able to get Web Site properties to take events from Measurement Protocol, which is what I would suggest people who read this question use.